# Bit manipulation of a single bit of an integer or bit masking

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

I would like to define a single bit of a register or a variable.
For example:
   #define Pin5 (5th bit of portA) //assuming porta is a 16 bit data type.

How can I define a single bit of a variable so that I can toggle that bit easily and make my code easier on my eyes. Please note that I want the bit value to become the RValue of the variable.

for example
   Pin5 = 1; //will result in the 5th bit of partA to be 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/50691/10396)

Comment: @AShelly Actually, Sam seems to be asking whether there is any way to define the bit as an lvalue, which is a more interesting question than just "how do I set it".

Comment: Oh good point.  The answer is unions of bitfields.

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, but then I read the comments on the bitfield answer at your link, and realized any use of bitfields is going to be quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

Given that bitfields are a bad idea, the cleanest I've been able to come up with for code "easy on the eyes" (i.e. wrapping as much syntax as possible into macros):

```
#define setbit(n) |=(1<<(n))
#define clrbit(n) &=~(1<<(n))
```

And then the code for your example would be:

```
portA setbit(5);
```